# How to Apply @Unique to an inherited field

Tags: jpa

is it possible to mark an inherited field as unique in the inheriting class using only annotations? to me the pendulum is more towards the NO side but want to confirm

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `uniqueConstraints` attribute of the `@Table` annotation:

```
@Table(uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"thecolumn"})})
```

NOTE that's only going to work for you if you don't have multiple entities using a SINGLE_TABLE inheritance strategy.